# Back Navigation in Action Bar Not working

Tags: android

I try to make back button in Action bar using this source. But it doesn't working.
Here's the source.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_found);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

This code showing no error, but when I test it on emulator, it force close.
Anyone know what's wrong?

Here's the Log Chat:

```
12-23 10:49:02.725: D/dalvikvm(693): GC_CONCURRENT freed 190K, 5% free 7100K/7431K, paused 4ms+105ms
12-23 10:49:33.345: D/AndroidRuntime(693): Shutting down VM
12-23 10:49:33.355: W/dalvikvm(693): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.okeschool/com.okeschool.ajax}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.okeschool.ajax.onCreate(ajax.java:15)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-23 10:49:33.405: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post logcat output? And some more information please ex. Are you using appcompat library or not?

Comment: I just added the log chat sir.

Comment: Are you sure the getActionBar() returns a ActionBar? Maybe you can debug or log the result to have a check if it is null or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define parent activity in the manifest?

Check this: [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html). I am pasting the content below to save time.

Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the `<activity>`element.

If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a `<meta-data>` element inside the `<activity>`. Then specify the parent activity as the value for `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, matching the `android:parentActivityName` attribute.

For example:

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have try it, but still force close.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem in detail? Also try to post the logs in case of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You parent activity has some state that is lost after you navigate away from it. When you return to it using the Up navigation, you are creating a new instance of the parent activity. If you want to re-use the old instance, with its state, you should add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.ParentActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.ChildActivity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ParentActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.app.ParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

More info
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Still force close sir

Comment: Can you post the `onCreate` method of the activity you are trying to launch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

On your AndroidManifest post this.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ActualActivity" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `getActionBar()` you have called in your `activity_location_found` is always used if your minSdkVersion is 11 or higher.

Try to call the `getSupportActionBar()` method instead.

this is your code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_found);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_found);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

If you split the declaration as you made:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Make sure you select the correct `ActionBar class`:
there is on `public abstract class ActionBar` which refers to `android.app`; and one `public asbstract class ActionBar` which refers to `android.support.v7.app`.

Maybe you have called `ActionBar class` with the wrong method.